# Search bar in title view not centered anymore when becoming first responder

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller, becomefirstresponder, titleview

In my navigation bar, I have a right bar button item representing a search button. When I press on it, the following function gets called

```
    func didTapSearchButton(sender: Any) {
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems?.removeLast()
        navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
        self.searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
```

The problem with the following code is that the search bar added in the title view is not centered, i.e it's not aligned with the back button.

[image]

Something interesting that I've noticed is that if I comment out the call `self.searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()`, my title view stays centered.

Can anyone help?

Comment: try this let textFieldOfSearchBar = self.searchController.searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
textFieldOfSearchBar?.textAlignment = .center

Comment: @JigarDarji I've tried, unfortunately it didn't work :(